# Reverse XSLT from a XML

Tags: xml, xslt, reverse

I have tried to write a XSLT File that converts data in to an XML File. But i am not very trained in XSLT. So i would like to ask if anyone has an way af reversing the XML file I have to the XSLT that creates is?

Comment: I'm afraid this is a manual process that requires programming skills and domain knowledge. But if you post input and output here, someone might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an input document `<question>What is the meaning of life?</question>` and a result document `<answer>42</answer>`, there are any number of possible stylesheets that will take that particular input and produce that particular output, and I'm afraid there is no algorithmic way of identifying any one of them as the one that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll have to do a deep dive in this then. Thanks for sharing the knowledge